# How to create and manage sessions in c++ ?

Tags: c++, session, authentication

I know how sessions work and have knowledge about authentication and authorization but I have only worked with them in php. upon authentication I used to start the session and store the session details in $_SESSION global array.

In c++ I have thought of creating an encrypted string "token" to store username password timestamp and let this token travel between various use cases. Before every submit option by user  I'll check this token to see it's freshness and validity.

Is this a good apporoach? Is there any other pre existing systematic approach to manage session in c++ ?

Comment: Why don't you use a static variable for this or a global variable that would stay live between various classes.

Comment: @pKs: Aside from the inherent hidden coupling that globals - including class status - bring, this solution naturally limits the application to only handling one active session at a time and is not easily modularised or extended.

Comment: Exactly Charles. That's the point.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is not like Java in the breadth of the functionality of the bundled libraries, so you need to extend the language with some extra libraries. I would suggest to look at below libraries...

http://rudeserver.com/session/index.html

http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/